# Any free UPC/Barcode DBs

Tags: barcode

I'm looking for a free UPC or Barcode database that is available for download. I have seen upcdataBase.com and a few others, but those do not allow for a free download of the db. File type is not a huge issue as I can work with SQL, csv, text, XML, json or anything else.

Anyone know where I can find one? I do not want a web service, I need an actual file or method of downloading all of the upcs or barcodes someone has. A large inclusive db would be great, but even a partial db would be great. 
Thanks

Comment: Note: I'd even be willing to pay up to 50 USD for a DB too!Free is preferred, but I'm also open to commercial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gregg London sells UPC databases in the form of a "Product Load Service". There is more information on their site: http://www.glondon.com/upcdatabase.html

Comment: For the benefit of anyone who may stumble into this post in the future, I would recommend strongly against using Mr. London's services. Been there, done that. Message me privately if you want to know more, but I would suggest you consider a more professional and reliable source.

Answer (score 2):

Logical Solutions (http://www.LogicalSo.com) sells [UPC barcode datamining software](http://www.LogicalSo.com) that scans the web for barcodes and product names, and build a database for you.

Comment: The site is in hebrew only it seems.

Answer (score 2):

You probably can make a quick mashup using: searchupc.com and upcdata.info and then retrieve product information from google product API.

Also, you can use AWSECommerceService API to retrieve something like this:

```
        ItemLookupRequest request = new ItemLookupRequest();
    request.getResponseGroup().add("Large");
    request.setIdType("UPC"); // TODO: need to change if it's EAC
    request.getItemId().add(upc);
    request.setSearchIndex("All");
```

Comment: Be careful when posting copy and paste boilerplate/verbatim answers to multiple questions, these tend to be flagged as "spammy" by the community. If you're doing this then it usually means the questions are duplicates so flag them as such instead.

Comment: yep, they're probably duplicated. thanks for the hint.

Comment: The Google product API is now deprecated and will be sunset on September 16, 2013.