# An open-source grocery database

Tags: database, mobile, open-source

I'm developing a product for retailers and I'm looking for an ready database of grocery SKUs for testing purposes. Would this be available anywhere? Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Excellent question, but pretty far off-topic.

Comment: Is SKU like UPC? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818329/any-free-upc-barcode-dbs

Comment: It would include UPC's but also things like barcodes for fruits which are NOT UPCs and do not include manufacturer codes.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a long shot, but if you go to http://publicdata.eu/ and select the "agriculture" group, you can limit the results by format of data (on the right hand side under "Resource Formats") and I know it isn't ideal, but they often have XLS and similar spreadsheet type formats with data regarding the agriculture industry in Europe. I'm not sure if that would include SKUs, but it might be a decent place to start?

Comment: Also most of the results will be in french or dutch, but an in-browser automated translation plug-in performs really well on that page.